# Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int'

Tags: c#

I am new at programing in C# and I try to make a simple program about book - I am asking how long does he/she need to read a book:

```
TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige = new int[SteviloPoglavijKjige];
NasloviPoglavijKnjige = new string[SteviloPoglavijKjige];

for (int i = 0; i < SteviloPoglavijKjige; i++) 
{
    Console.Write("Vpiši naslov {0,2}. poglavij: ", i + 1);
    NasloviPoglavijKnjige[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Vpiši koliko časa porabiš za branje knjige: ");
            TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Napaka pri vnosu števila: ");
        }
    }
```

The errors I am getting are:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'int' 
Error   2   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'int'
```

Should I write all in small letters?

Comment: first erros should be - TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige = new int[SteviloPoglavijKjige];

Comment: second erro should be -  TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: `SteviloPoglavijKjige` is this perviously declared as a number?! And please translate your code into english so people can help you better!

Comment: Can you tell us which lines are ones where the errors happen?

Comment: How is `TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige` declared?

Comment: Which language are you following in your code?

Comment: @Sean87 well you can spot errors whatever the variable and method names are, can't you? ;) This isn't an algorithmic question, rather a syntax error.

Comment: @jv42 well in this particular case you are right :P But I am against writing code in local language! At some point it will hurt!

Comment: @Sean87 agreed. I always write code and code related stuff in English, even on personal/tinker projects.

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you get, it seems you haven't declared `TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige` as an array of ints, but as a single int.

```
int[] TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige;
```

This should fix it.

---

To answer your question about casing, you can use whatever you like for your identifiers, the compiler won't care, but usual conventions use 'camelCase' for variables, ie starting with a lower case letter, sometimes with a '*' or 'm*' prefix.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and helping out

Answer (score 0):

Is "TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige" of type int[] ?

```
int[] TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige = new int[SteviloPoglavijKjige];
```

....

Comment: Befor I started I put it like that out int TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige

Answer (score 0):

The error is here. The left side should be an array of type `int` as follows.

```
int[] TrajanjeČasaBranjaKnjige = new int[SteviloPoglavijKjige];
```